# Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas? Ganache BSC Fork

Tags: javascript, web3js, ganache

I'm running Ganache from cli forked from BSC Mainnet:

```
ganache -f https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org -m MNEMONIC-BIP39-STYLE
```

I have a super simple script ran through node to read balances direct from Ganache (and thus the BSC mainnet) that looks like this:

index.js:

```
(async () => {
    const Web3 = new require('web3')
    
    const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545')
    let web3 = new Web3(provider)
    
    let block = await web3.eth.getBlock('latest');
    //console.log(block)
    
    const token_busd = "0x4fabb145d64652a948d72533023f6e7a623c7c53";
    const token_dai  = "0x1af3f329e8be154074d8769d1ffa4ee058b1dbc3";
    const token_wbnb = "0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c";
    
    //const bep20ABI = [{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"guy","type":"address"},{"name":"wad","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"src","type":"address"},{"name":"dst","type":"address"},{"name":"wad","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"wad","type":"uint256"}],"name":"withdraw","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"decimals","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint8"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"dst","type":"address"},{"name":"wad","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"deposit","outputs":[],"payable":true,"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"},{"name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"allowance","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"payable":true,"stateMutability":"payable","type":"fallback"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"src","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"guy","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"wad","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Approval","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"src","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"dst","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"wad","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"dst","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"wad","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Deposit","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"src","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"wad","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Withdrawal","type":"event"}];
    const minABI = [
      // balanceOf
      {
        constant: true,
        inputs: [{ name: "_owner", type: "address" }],
        name: "balanceOf",
        outputs: [{ name: "balance", type: "uint256" }],
        type: "function",
      },
    ];

    const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(minABI, token_wbnb.toLowerCase());
    //console.log(contract)
    
    const result = await contract.methods.balanceOf("[my address here]").call();
    console.log(result)

})();
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "test_1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "web3": "^1.6.0"
  }
}
```

Now if I query the balanceOf token_dai or token_wbnb I get result of 0 which is correct (I have none :( ), but if I query token_busd or token_wbnb I get the error:

```
        throw new Error('Returned values aren\'t valid, did it run Out of Gas? ' +
              ^

Error: Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas? You might also see this error if you are not using the correct ABI for the contract you are retrieving data from, requesting data from a block number that does not exist, or querying a node which is not fully synced.
    at ABICoder.decodeParametersWith (C:\DEVL\test_1\node_modules\web3-eth-abi\lib\index.js:297:15)
    at ABICoder.decodeParameters (C:\DEVL\test_1\node_modules\web3-eth-abi\lib\index.js:284:17)
    at Contract._decodeMethodReturn (C:\DEVL\test_1\node_modules\web3-eth-contract\lib\index.js:469:22)
    at Method.outputFormatter (C:\DEVL\test_1\node_modules\web3-eth-contract\lib\index.js:759:42)
    at Method.formatOutput (C:\DEVL\test_1\node_modules\web3-core-method\lib\index.js:146:54)
    at sendTxCallback (C:\DEVL\test_1\node_modules\web3-core-method\lib\index.js:522:33)
    at C:\DEVL\test_1\node_modules\web3-core-requestmanager\lib\index.js:307:9
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (C:\DEVL\test_1\node_modules\web3-providers-http\lib\index.js:98:13)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (C:\DEVL\test_1\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist\xml-http-request-event-target.js:34:22)
    at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (C:\DEVL\test_1\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist\xml-http-request.js:208:14)
    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (C:\DEVL\test_1\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist\xml-http-request.js:318:14)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\DEVL\test_1\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist\xml-http-request.js:289:61)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:402:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1343:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
```

I checked the addresses on bscscan, coingecko etc to confirm the correct contract address. It looks right to me, so I don't understand why its throwing the error. I hope the address is just wrong!

Comment: I'm not sure why it fails but If you wrap your `balanceOf` call in a [try...catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) block you can log the error and continue running instead of needing to restart your service.

Answer (score 0):

So while its not a permanent solution, ctrl-c!!  Kill ganache and restart it!

I'm finding that if I get the above error, or any error, i'll go and kill Ganache, then restart it.  Most of the time I'll retry my code and i get the correct result, no error.